# Show that $\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $a\in \mathbb{R}:a>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$. Furthermore $(a_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{R}$: $$a_1=1+a \text{ and } a_{n+1}=a_n\left(1+\frac{a-a_n^k} {ka_n^k}\right) \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Now I have to show that

> $$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n$$

for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I have been looking at this problem for quite some time now, and I don't understand what's going on here. How do I know what $a_n$ even is? And where do I even start with the proof? I have never encountered that kind of sequence.

Comment: Did you try induction ?

Comment: Interesting, How do I do that?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic are you having trouble with the induction itself or aren't you familiar with induction?

Comment: I am familiar with the idea of induction, but I don't see how induction can be applied here.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic When something is defined by a recursion, using inductoin to show properties of that is usually the natural choice. Give it a try to  show $a_{n+1}\le a_n$ from $a_n\ge\sqrt[k]a>0$, for a start

Comment: What's $a_n$? Do I have to show $a_n\left(1+\frac{a-a_n^k} {ka_n^k}\right)\leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n\left(1+\frac{a-a_n^k} {ka_n^k}\right)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $a\in \mathbb{R}:a>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$. Furthermore $(a_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathbb{R}$: $$a_1=1+a \text{ and } a_{n+1}=a_n\left(1+\frac{a-a_n^k} {ka_n^k}\right) \text{ for } n\in \mathbb{N}$$
We wish to show that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$:
$$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{n+1}\leq a_n$$

We will induct on $n$,  let's start with $n=1$, we need to show that:
$$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{2}\leq a_1$$
Observe indeed that this means: 
$$a_2=a_1\left(1+\frac{a-a_1^k} {ka_1^k}\right)=(1+a)\left(1+\frac{a-(1+a)^k} {k(1+a)^k}\right)=(1+a)(1 + \frac{a}{k(1+a)^k} - \frac{1}{k})$$
we know that $k\geq 2$ so $\frac{1}{k } \leq 2$ and since $a>0$ also $ \frac{1}{(1+a)^k} \leq \frac{1}{(1+a)^2}$
$$a_2 \leq (1+a)(1+ \frac{a}{2(1+a)^2} -\frac{1}{2})=(1+a) + \frac{a}{2(1+a)}-\frac{1}{2} $$ $$=(1+a) + \frac{1}{2(\frac{1}{a}+1)}-\frac{1}{2}<(1+a)+ \frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2}=1+a_1$$
so $a_2 \leq a_1$. Now we also need to prove that $\sqrt[k]{a} \leq a_2$ or $a \leq a_2^k$, we get:
$$a_2^k=(1+a)^k(1 + \frac{a}{k(1+a)^k} - \frac{1}{k})^k > (1+a)^k(1+ \frac{a}{k}-\frac{1}{k})^k = (1+a+\frac{a}{k} +\frac{a^2}{k}-\frac{a}{k}-\frac{1}{k})^k $$  $$a_2^k > (1+a+\frac{a^2}{k}-\frac{1}{k})^k $$
We now use that $(1+x)^k \geq 1 + kx$, for natural numbers $k$ and positive $1+x$. We know the smallest value for $k$ is $2$, so $(1+a+\frac{a^2}{k}-\frac{1}{k})>(1+a-\frac{1}{2})>\frac{1}{2}+a>0$, we thus get by this Bernoulli estimate:
$$a_2^k \geq 1 + k(a+\frac{a^2}{k}-\frac{1}{k})=ak + a^2> 2a +a^2 >a$$
And thus:
$$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{2}\leq a_1$$

Now suppose for some natural number $l$, we have the **induction hypothesis**:
$$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{l}\leq a_{l-1}$$

Your task, using this, will be to show that now we also have:
$$\sqrt[k]{a}\leq a_{l+1}\leq a_{l}$$
This would complete the proof. Good luck! happy estimating.

Comment: Notice this was only the base case, you still need to estimate to make the step from $l$ to $l+1$, as hinted by Hagen von Eitzen.

Comment: So what we KNOW to be true is that the hypothesis holds, then our task will be to show that one step later the inequality still holds. You will have to combine the hypothesis together with the definition of your $a_{n+1}$

Comment: Two steps: $a_ {l+1}\leq a_l $ and $ \sqrt[k]{a} \leq a_{l+1}$, just one step at a time. Often you can draw inspiration from the base case though. But the trick in this case is again to use some estimations, basically the $a_{n+1}$ must eventually approach $\sqrt[k]{a}$, as it is a decreasing sequence that is bounded below and therefore it must converge to the infimum.

Comment: I would first write $a_{l+1}$ in terms of $a_l$ using the definition, and then repeat, writing $a_{l}$ in terms of $a_{l-1}$ , then probably throw some positive terms away and use the induction hypothesis since we know that $a_{l-1} \geq a_l$. But trying never hurted anybody I guess :)

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to find $a_n$?

Comment: You don't need to find $a_n$, that's not the point, the point is to show that a sequence satisfying the definition is bounded below by some $a^{1/k}$ and it is decreasing, that's all you need to prove. You are not asked to find such a sequence.